# What is the equivalent of jQuery function in Prototypejs?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What is the equivalent of jQuery's

**closest()** function in prototypeJS?

and **html()** function in prototypeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the .html() function looks like this in prototype

To retrieve the html

```
$('fruits').innerHTML;
// -> '<ul id="favorite"><li>kiwi</li><li>banana</li><li>apple</li></ul>'
```

To change the html

```
$('fruits').update('kiwi, banana and apple');
// -> HTMLElement
```

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update

Comment: Using update, I can set the HTML only and how about retrieve?

in jQuery, $('#fruits').html() --provide the innerHTML of element#fruit and
$('#fruits').html('kiwi,banana and apple') --set the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read [`getOffsetParent`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getOffsetParent) for `closest()` and [`update`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update)  for `html()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ which represents closest() is not equivalent to getOffsetParent

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `html()` can set and retrieve html text whereas, prototype has no such equivalent. Prototype has only `update()` which can set html of an element. There is no method to retrieve html text like jQuery. However, using innerHTML, we can get and set html text.

jQuery's `closest()` can be replaced by prototype `up()` method, as per my understanding.

Thank you so much for all of your support.